# Python SSL Wrong Version Number for webpage urllib request

Tags: python, html, ssl, urllib, python-re

I am running a request to get IP addresses from a website but keep running into a problem half of the time where it gives the following error. It tells me that my SSL is the wrong version, I have searched all over the web but haven't found anything helpful.

What happens is that I am looping over a list of IP addresses and I get about halfway through the loop and it throws the error below.

```
def ipInfo(addr=''):
    try:
        url = f'https://tools.keycdn.com/geo?host={addr}'
    except:
        return 'Error'
    #f = requests.get(url, verify=False, ssl)
    x = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ssl.SSLContext())
    #c = str(f.content)
    c = str(x.read())
    number = re.compile('Country</dt><dd class="col-8 text-monospace">')
    attempt = number.search(c)
    if attempt is not None:
        attempt = attempt.span()
        l = list(attempt)
        val = c[l[1]:l[1]+25].split('<')[0]
        return val
    else:
        return 'No country associated'
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1318                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1319                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1320             except OSError as err: # timeout error

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1251         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1252         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1253 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1297             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1298         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1299 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1246             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1247         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1248 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    965             if self.auto_open:
--> 966                 self.connect()
    967             else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)
   1421             self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
-> 1422                                                   server_hostname=server_hostname)
   1423 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    422             context=self,
--> 423             session=session
    424         )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
    869                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 870                     self.do_handshake()
    871             except (OSError, ValueError):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1138                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1139             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1140         finally:

SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-198-9aba5213355b> in <module>
      2 d = {}
      3 for x in IPs:
----> 4     d[x] = ipInfo(x)
      5 finish = time.time()
      6 print(finish - start)

<ipython-input-197-7e56c6097581> in ipInfo(addr)
      5         return 'Error'
      6     #f = requests.get(url, verify=False, ssl)
----> 7     x = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ssl.SSLContext())
      8     #c = str(f.content)
      9     c = str(x.read())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    523             req = meth(req)
    524 
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 
    527         # post-process response

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    541         protocol = req.type
    542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 543                                   '_open', req)
    544         if result:
    545             return result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in https_open(self, req)
   1360         def https_open(self, req):
   1361             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
-> 1362                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
   1363 
   1364         https_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1319                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1320             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1321                 raise URLError(err)
   1322             r = h.getresponse()
   1323         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [web-page](https://tools.keycdn.com/geo) being queried states

> We are rate limiting requests (3r/s) to avoid overload of the system

and your stacktrace output makes multiple references to request time-outs so I'd say the error is likely due to the web-app temporarily blocking you due to the number of requests being submitted.

You could test this theory by making use of the `urllib.request.urlopen()` function's optional [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) parameter;

> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
> blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
> global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works
> for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections.

Comment: I added a timeout but now instead, I get a timeout error that says, "The read operation timed out"

Comment: Understood, maybe try different values for the timeout see if that has any effect. Also, try making a request for just one IP to see if that works (perhaps the server blocks access from your IP for a specific time-period after making too many requests). I'll delete this answer if this turns out to be of no use